# End to end Testing Elasticsearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, integration-testing, nest, in-memory-database

A quick question relating the end to end Elasticsearch testing using Nest in c#.
I was able to setup an InMemoryConnection for Elasticsearch and be able to get a mock response when I do the search query. The problem is when I run the delete query, it doesn't delete the data. Is there a way to test it end to end? Thank you

Comment: I don't quite get what you want. You would mock the method that deletes the document and return an expected response. A mock only defines the responses of those dependencies not the actual behavior of the dependency.  So if you test deletions you test that your code reacts correctly to the response from (the mocked) Elasticsearch. If it would have been deleted in a real elasticsearch environment is irrelevant here.

Comment: You tagged this as integration test. In that case you want to take a real Elasticsearch instance and not a mocked client.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.